# Google Sheet Script not fully executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I'm using a Google Form to trigger this script. 
When I run the script with the Play button it works perfect.
When I let the onsubmit trigger run it, the check box populates fine but the setValue date does not.
I've also tried using `setFormula` but I get the same result.

```
function AddCheckBox_toSchoolLunchForm(F) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 8);
  range.clearContent();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
  var FormulaCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 10);
  FormulaCell.setFormula("=DATEVALUE(A" + (sheet.getLastRow()) + ")");
}
```

[image: Example of result from a Manual Code run]

[image: Example of result from a Triggered Code Run]

The end goal is to have column J populate with the shot formatted date from column A each time the form is submitted.
I need this format to run a countIfs on another sheet.

Another option would be to somehow embed a format tag into this CountIfs command so that they match.

```
=COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!J:J,A2,'Form Responses 1'!D:D,B2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

### If you have problems running a function on trigger while it works as intended without a trigger, check the following:

- For heavy files / form data they can be a delay in populating the sheet with new form data.

  - To avoid conflicts, give the spreadsheet some time to populate the new row before retrieving `sheet.getLastRow()` or accessing data in the sheet.
  - You can dot is easily e.g. with [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).
- Check that your trigger has been installed correctly. For this check that

  - the type of trigger is correct
  - the trigger is bound to the correct function
  - avoid conflicts by creating a new trigger when renaming the funciton.
- Check that the problem is not due to trigger [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)
- This is a common error source when using simple triggers.
- Check that account under whose authorization the trigger is running has permissions to edit the sheet  /range. This is important to check when the trigger owner is a diferent person that the person who runs the script manualy.
- Note that for `setFormula()` it is not necessary to incorporate the `=` into the formula
- Note that `DATEVALUE()` will only return the expected result when the cell is formatted correctly as a date

Comment: I tried adding the sleep in two places and it was not successful.
Currently I am the only one using this for in a testing situation.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your spreadsheet to troubleshoot? And maybe also the form if there is no confidential information.

Comment: Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ze40T2p3-Kn4-iz-K7iWo2zIGdpR94PWaXaFmY0Mbok/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc7yUUY0QFTJup2AOD9CG1RuP8lG5sVxIZXgjUdG7QJDWM5Vg/viewform

Comment: Thank you for offering to help

Comment: Done, Thank You.

Comment: I see the issue now - you created the wrong trigger. Change `Select event type` from `On open` to `On from Submit`. Small side note: When you sue `setFormula` isntead os `setValue` you can skip the `=`.

Comment: When I look at the trigger I see it set as  "From spreadsheet - On form submit"

Comment: I see that under Edit -- Current Project triggers

Comment: It seems like the trigger is authorized by a person who does not have writing access. Keep in mind that it if you comment away the setting of checkbox - there will still be a checkbox. Is there another script that sets checkboxes. Your best bet is to create a new destination spreadsheet and bind your script to it to avoid conflict with other scripts / formulas that might apply to the curernt one.

Comment: Found it. the trigger was set to run myFunction, I changed it to the proper add checkbox function and its working. It's odd because I don't have a myFunction defined....?

Comment: Thank You SOOOOO much for your help. I truly appreciate it!

Comment: FYI, I did flag your answer as correct, but I'm new so it won't show publicly.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If the trigger is bound to `myFunction` and you don't have a function `myFunction` in your script-probably you renamed your function after binding the trigger to it.